# Plotting Voxel in mathematica

Tags: image3d

I am developping a 3D reconstruction application.  I recuperate the voxels coordinates (the coordinate of each voxel) of the object that I need to reconstruct. Each voxel have a dimensions like this 5cm*5cm*5cm. I need to reconstruct this volume. I try to use `Image3D`  function by put just a 3d binary table representing the voxels that belongs to volume but I could not change the size of each voxel. Any help please?

Comment: The size of every voxel in a grid is always the same, by definition.

Comment: @ssch, yes of course, In my case, the dimension of each pixel is 5cm*5cm*5cm. What is wrong?

Comment: Add a link to your data @phdstudent. That will automagically make your question more appealing :)

Comment: @Zet, I need any example to construct voxel.

Comment: @Zet, I developped the code. It is so easy. thanks

Comment: The absolute size of your voxels only matters if you are combining with other graphics. What problem are you having specifically?

Comment: I suspect you'll get best performance if you stick with Image3D. Scale everything else into the unit voxel space defined by the image.  Or cross your fingers, maybe soon Wolfram will give us `Inset3D`..:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to get pseudo-voxels using `Cuboid` (mainly for versions <9):

```
{dx, dy, dz} = {5, 5, 5};

Graphics3D[
 Table[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[.1], Hue[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]/25], 
   Cuboid[{x, y, z} - {dx, dy, dz}/2, {x, y, z} + {dx, dy, dz}/
      2]}, {x, -25, 25, dx}, {y, -25, 25, dy}, {z, -25, 25, dz}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or using other increments:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

... and just to give an impression of the visual differences between `Raster3D` (left) and  `Cuboid` (right):

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Raster3D[{{{{1, 0, 0}}}}], EdgeForm[None], 
Red, Cuboid[{2, 0, 0}]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Using [Raster3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Raster3D.html) :

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5],Raster3D[RandomReal[1,{5,5,5,3}]]}, Axes-> True]
```

[image: unit voxel]

This will generate unit voxels, while the following creates 5x5x5 unit voxels:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5],Raster3D[RandomReal[1,{5,5,5,3}],{{0,0,0},{25,25,25}}]}, Axes-> True]
```

[image: 5x5x5 voxels]

Perhaps this will clarify the sizes:

```
Show[{
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5],Raster3D[RandomReal[1,{5,5,5,3}]]}],
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5],Raster3D[RandomReal[1,{5,5,5,3}],{{10,0,0},{35,25,25}}]}]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: What is the relation between my question and your solution?

Comment: @phdstudent you *were* asking 5x5x5 voxels,  right?

Comment: @YvesKlett  What is the information illustrated by  `RandomReal[1,{5,5,5,3}] ` ? Is this matrix contains the center or the opposite corner of each voxel or… what?

Comment: @phdstudent please look up the documentation for `Raster3D`, esp. under Scope->Specification.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for Plotting voxel grid:

```
   PlottingVoxel[{VoxCenter_, VoxH_, VoxL_, VoxP_}] := 
   Module[{Ip, CoordVox}, (
  Ip = VoxCenter - N[{VoxH/2, VoxL/2, VoxP/2}];
  CoordVox = {{Ip, Ip + {VoxH, 0, 0}, Ip + {VoxH, VoxP, 0}, 
  Ip + {0, VoxP, 0}},
  {Ip, Ip + {VoxH, 0, 0}, Ip + {VoxH, 0, VoxL}, 
  Ip + {0, 0, VoxL}},
  {Ip + {0, 0, VoxL}, Ip + {VoxH, 0, VoxL}, 
  Ip + {VoxH, VoxL, VoxL}, Ip + {0, VoxP, VoxL}},
  {Ip + {0, 0, VoxL}, Ip + {0, VoxP, VoxL}, Ip + {0, VoxP, 0}, 
  Ip},
   {Ip + {0, VoxP, 0}, Ip + {VoxH, VoxP, 0}, 
  Ip + {VoxH, VoxP, VoxL}, Ip + {0, VoxP, VoxL}},
  {Ip + {VoxH, 0, 0}, Ip + {VoxH, VoxP, 0}, 
  Ip + {VoxH, VoxP, VoxL}, Ip + {VoxH, 0, VoxL}}};
  Polygon[CoordVox]

  )]

  Note:
  VoxCenter=center of voxel.
  VoxH,VoxL,VoxP is the dimension of the voxel.
```

Exemple:

```
 Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Green], EdgeForm[Thick], Opacity[0.3], 
 PlottingVoxel[{#, 1, 1, 1}] & /@ 
 Flatten[Table[{x, y, z}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, {z, 0, 5}], 2], 
 FaceForm[Blue], Opacity[.4]}]
```

Result:
       [image]

Comment: Those are not really voxels, though. To similar effect, you could use `Cuboid` (e.g. cribbed from the docs: `Graphics3D[
 Table[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[.1], Hue[RandomReal[]], 
   Cuboid[RandomReal[4, 3]]}, {40}]]` )

Comment: @YvesKlett, Why did you say that my solution is not a real voxels? I do not understand the difference? I used the polygon to make a cuboid and you used the cuboid directly.

Comment: Another things, I try your solution and it get the same excution time that my own!Please do you can try the code for a grid with dimensions 300,300,300 and the diemension of each voxels is 5*5*5?

Comment: From a rendering point, a cuboid set of polygon faces is not the same as a voxel (think ray-tracing).

Comment: Ok! may be you are right! I have not a deep idea about ray tracing. But, How can I fix the computation problem?

Comment: My version will not differ much in terms of performance.I would recommend to go with @chuy´s solution, which is the way to go starting with V9.