# How to define a custom 2/3D graphic primitive like built-in?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, splines, built-in-symbols

There are lots of basic *graphic-primitives* in *Mathematica*, such as 2D- primitive: `Line[], Circle[], Disk[]` and 3D-primitive: `Cylinder[], BSplineSurface[], Sphere[], Cuboid[]`,etc.

In general, they own the following basic usage if memory serves:

```
Graphics(*Graphics3D*)[
  {primitiveStyle1, primitive1[arg1],
   primitiveStyle2, primitive2[arg2]}]

Graphics(*Graphics3D*)[
  {{primitiveStyle1, primitive1[arg1],
    primitiveStyle2, primitive2[arg2]}}]
```

where, `primitiveStyle` is one/several of the member of `Thick, Green` and so on.

For this question, the MSE has owned two similar threads like:

- [How to create custom Graphics primitive?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27184/how-to-create-custom-graphics-primitive)
- [Define new 3D graphics primitives in Mathematica 9](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39106/define-new-3d-graphics-primitives-in-mathematica-9?lq=1)

For the first question, [*Simon Woods*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) has given a good [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27184/how-to-create-custom-graphics-primitive/27209#27209) for **2D**-case. However, the **detail** about the implementation for the 2D primitive was **not** described. In addtion, [*m_goldberg*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) also given a solution with the help of the *built-in* primitive.

---

For instance, now I have to create a 3D primitive `BezierSurface[]` via the *built-in* `BezierFunction[]`, I tried using `UpValues[]` as follows:

```
BezierSurface /: Graphics3D[BezierSurface[ctrlnets_]] :=
  ParametricPlot3D[
    BezierFunction[ctrlnets][u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]
```

Now we have a test

```
cpts = Table[{i, j, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
Graphics3D[BezierSurface[cpts]]
```

[image]

But, for `Graphics3D[{BezierSurface[cpts]}]`, it failed:(. I tried to change the `UpValues[]` defintion:

```
BezierSurface /: Graphics3D[{BezierSurface[ctrlnets_]}] :=
  ParametricPlot3D[
    BezierFunction[ctrlnets][u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]
```

which gives me `TagSetDelayed::tagpos:` error.

[image]

For the `BSplineSurface[]`, which own many usages

```
(*basic usage 1*)
Graphics3D[BSplineSurface[cpts]]

(*basic usage 2*)
Graphics3D[{BSplineSurface[cpts]}]

(*adding style*)
Graphics3D[{Pink, EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], Specularity[White, 50], 
            BSplineSurface[cpts]}]

(*adding other primitives*)
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Medium], Blue, Map[Point, cpts], 
            Pink, BSplineSurface[cpts]}]

(*another usage*)
Graphics3D[{{Blue, Cylinder[]}, 
            {Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 2}]}}]
```

---

So my question is:

- how to make user-defined 3D primitive `BezierSurface[]` works like *built-in* `BSplineSurface[]`?

Comment: What you call `primitiveStyle` is often referred to as a *directive*.

Comment: @J.M. Did you means `Directive[g1,g2,...]`, represents a single graphics directive composed of the directives `g1,g2,...` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the symbol used to treat a group of directives as a single directive. :)

Comment: You could do something less fancy like, `BezierSurface[ctrlnets_] := First@ParametricPlot3D[...]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks a lot:) In general, I seldom used `Directive[]`. Instead, I used this style: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thick, Dashed}]` rather than `PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Thick, Dashed]`

Comment: @wxffles Yes, this is indeed a solution. However,  `BSplineSurface[cpts]` just returns itself, while `BezierSurface[cpts]` returns a lot of **3D points group**.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If my answer for the 2D case lacks detail, it's because `` Typeset`MakeBoxes `` is an internal, undocumented function. That makes it hard to say anything authoritative about how it works. Essentially though, we are defining the custom primitive in such a way that the definition only applies during conversion of a graphics expression to boxes.

Here's a version of `createPrimitive` adapted for Graphics3D.

```
SetAttributes[createPrimitive3D, HoldAll]

createPrimitive3D[patt_, expr_] :=
 Typeset`MakeBoxes[p : patt, fmt_, Graphics3D] :=
  With[{e = expr}, Typeset`MakeBoxes[Interpretation[e, p], fmt, Graphics3D]]
```

You use it like `SetDelayed`, with a pattern as the first argument and the definition as the second:

```
createPrimitive3D[BezierSurface[ctrlnets_],
 FirstCase[
  ParametricPlot3D[BezierFunction[ctrlnets][u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}],
  _GraphicsComplex]]
```

`BezierSurface` does not evaluate...

```
cpts = Table[{i, j, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 3}, {j, 3}];    
BezierSurface[cpts]

(* BezierSurface[{{{1, 1, -0.559961}, {1, 2, -0.470345}, {1, 3, 0.271683}},
   {{2, 1, 0.855812}, {2, 2, -0.378208}, {2, 3, 0.476702}}, 
   {{3, 1, -0.106064}, {3, 2, -0.462438}, {3, 3, 0.269039}}}] *)
```

...except when displayed in `Graphics3D`

```
Graphics3D[BezierSurface[cpts]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1! Thanks very very much:) I tested the following cases:(1) `Graphics3D[BezierSurface[cpts]]`, (2) `Graphics3D[{BezierSurface[cpts]}]`, (3) `Graphics3D[{BezierSurface[cpts], BSplineSurface[cpts]}]`, (4) `Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4], BezierSurface[cpts]}]`, (5) `Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 10], Red, BezierSurface[cpts]}]`. And I discovered that the last case(5) [failed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7SBzv.png).

Comment: In addtion, I also noticed that the built-in `BSplineSurface[]` didn't apply the `ParametricPlot3D[]` to sample the 3D points, please see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/J0grL.png) :)

Comment: The `GraphicsComplex` extracted from `ParametricPlot3D` contains its own colouring directives which is why your attempt to recolour it doesn't work. To get full control of the styling you probably want to extract only the polygons.

Comment: `BSplineSurface` does not need to construct a polygon representation, it displays as a `BSplineSurface3DBox` which is drawn directly by the front end.

Comment: So, is it possible for the **user** to write a analogous function called `BezierSurface3DBox[]` to let the front-end draw that surface directly?

Comment: You would need to change the front end code to add instructions for how to typeset (draw) that new box type. As far as I know you would need to work at Wolfram Research to do that.

Comment: OK, thank you. I sent a e-mail to the CEO of *WRI*, **Stephen Wolfram** in July 4.  and two weeks later, I got this [response](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NOkGP.png) from wolfram office. In addtion, I have a friend work in *WRI*, he told me that he known a **premitive developer**. Unfortunately, that primitive developer didn't know how to do.:(

Comment: I find that I have to supply the 3rd and 4th argument to `FirstCase` in order for this to work in V12.