# Evaluation leak from Dynamic in Button's action

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, button

```
a = 1;

Button["Print", a++]
Button["Print", Dynamic[a++]]
Button["Print", Dynamic[a++];]
Button["Print", {Dynamic[a++]}]

Dynamic @ a
```

The second `Button` is not supposed to change the value of `a` but it does.

Have I missed something or is it a bug?

---

Why it is not supposed to?

> `Button[label,action]` [...] evaluates action whenever it is clicked.

Evaluation is supposed to leave `Dynamic` intakt and if it is part of returned result `MakeBoxes` will create `DynamicBox` which is supposed to be handled by `FrontEnd` which should send contents to evaluation when needed.

Yet the `Button` isn't creating any visible result when clicked.

---

While `Button["Print", Dynamic[a++]]` isn't useful in general, the leak is the leak.

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3609709] was created
>
> [...]  I have filed an incident report with the information you provided.
>
> [...] I have also filed a second incident report for the documentation example [...]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To understand this, look at the typesetting:

```
In[1]:= ToBoxes[Button["Print", Dynamic[a++]]] // InputForm

Out[1]//InputForm=
ButtonBox["\"Print\"", ButtonFunction :> Dynamic[a++], Appearance -> Automatic, 
 Evaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Preemptive"]
```

Front end options, which includes all box options, can take `Dynamic` heads.  That basically means that the FE will compute the value of the `Dynamic` and use it for the option.  And that it will be updated whenever a `Dynamic` dependency updates.

Because `Button` is passing its second argument unmolested to the right-hand side of `ButtonFunction`, it looks like a `Dynamic` rhs which needs to be computed by the FE.  And that computation increments a++.

At first, I was surprised that it didn't increment by virtue of simply being displayed on the screen.  I.e., I might have expected `a` to be 2 even before you pressed the button.  As it turns out, it doesn't because it's in a class of options which are treated as always held, until they're actually used.  Other such options include the `Initialization`, `Deinitialization`, and `TrackedSymbols` options of various boxes.  And too many more to list, but only a small number of the overall number of options.

So, is it a bug?  Maybe.  These "always-held" options certainly don't gain any benefit from `Dynamic` handling.  However, if we added special handling for them, then we'd have to list all of the options and document why they're excluded from standard `Dynamic` handling, which I think would be burdensome for everyone.  I think I would lean towards calling it not a bug.

I think the better thing in this case would be to properly document that the second argument of `Button` is passed to `ButtonBoxOptions->ButtonFunction`.

Comment: Am I the only one who gets excited upon reading **"answered (by)
John Fultz"** on the front page?  I know I am almost certainly about to learn something, and this was no exception.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Considering that, I'd say it's expected and should be left to not create exceptions. Let me suggest adding the last paragraph of your answer to *Details and Options* with a link to *Possible Issues* section where extended explanation will be given + `Button[lable, Dynamic[action]]` added to usage. Briefly mentioning `ButtonFunction` will probably be missed or will confuse a user who is unaware of subtleties.

Comment: Let me abuse the fact that you are around :) Quick question, is there any purpose why `Button` inserts styling options even though it's a basic `Button`? I mean, `Appearance` is inserted what makes impossible to put `BaseStyle->ButtonBoxOptions->Appearance->_` outside and hope that it will be inherited. Or maybe the best way is to work with `RawBoxes + controllerBox` so that one can use `controllerBoxOptions` to style them collectively?

Comment: @Kuba, yes, your documentation suggestion is quite reasonable.  As for the `Appearance` option...well, there *is* a reason, but I'm not sure it's a very justifiable one.  Basically, it was a hack to deal with the default options we wanted for `Button` in v6 without breaking backward compatibility with `ButtonBox`es that were generated pre-v6.  It's a decision which seemed sensible (albeit a bit hacky) at the time, but looks increasingly silly today.  I would be willing to call the current behavior a minor bug.

Comment: Hi,John Fultz,I know you are a frontend developer in WRI, so could I ask you a question about *Mathematica* **premitive**, about the detail, please see this [thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111403/how-to-define-a-custom-2-3d-graphic-primitive-like-built-in) Thanks:)