# Prevent Grid from overriding GridBoxItemSize from Stylesheet

Tags: front-end, grid-layouts, stylesheet, inheritance

I have problems getting the Stylesheet settings for `GridBoxOptions`/`GridBoxItemSize` to be applied to `Grid` expressions. Consider the following example:

```
(* Create a new Stylesheet with a GridTest style that sets the column widths of GridBox *)
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
   {
    Cell[
     StyleData["GridTest"],
     GridBoxOptions -> {
       GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {Scaled@0.7, {Scaled@0.3}}}
       }
     ]
    }
   ]
 ]

(* Create a cell containing a Grid expression *)
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Grid[{{"a", "b"}}], "GridTest"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* Manually create the GridBox *)
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData@GridBox@{{"a", "b"}}, "GridTest"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, the setting from the Stylesheet is only applied to the case where the `GridBox` is manually built. Inspecting the box structure of the automatically generated `GridBox` reveals the problem:

```
ToBoxes@Grid[{{"a", "b"}}]
(* TagBox[
    GridBox[
     {{"\"a\"", "\"b\""}},
     AutoDelete -> False,
     GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}
    ],
    "Grid"
   ] *)
```

Apparently, `ToBoxes` automatically adds a default for `GridBoxItemSize`, which obviously overrides the Stylesheet default.

The question is now: *How can I convert a `Grid` expression into a box structure such that the Stylesheet options are not randomly overridden?*

I've tried to specify things like `ItemSize->{}` or `ItemSize->Inherited`, but they do not work. There seems to be another issue that causes `ToBoxes` to replace `ItemSize->Inherited` with `GridBoxItemSize->{}`, rather than `GridBoxItemSize->Inherited` (which would behave properly).

The reason why I need this: I need to generate a cell containing a `GridBox` from a `Grid` expression with user defined option values and have it respect the stylesheet defaults. Since the mapping from `Grid` options to `GridBoxOptions` is not documented, I can't ask the user to provide the `GridBox` options directly. Of course, I could manually perform the mapping or try to detect which options need to be deleted, this feels hacky and partly relies on undocumented behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Intro

It is not an isolated problem, similar limitation affects e.g. `Button's` `Appearance`. And it is internally considered a *minor bug*, read more in comments to that answer:

[Evaluation leak from Dynamic in Button's action](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115888/evaluation-leak-from-dynamic-in-buttons-action/116030#comment315016_116030)

#### Solution

Summing up, I don't think there is an easy way. You either have to modify built-in `` GridDump`GridToBoxes `` definitions or you need to insert `GridBoxItemSize -> Inherited` to your `Grids`. E.g.:

```
Grid[{{"a", "b"}}
, GridBoxItemSize -> Inherited,  BaseStyle -> {"GridTest"}
]
```

#### Grumble

That obviously makes coding annoying so one (I) ends up with `myGrid` and `myButton` aliases where I put every tweak I need.

But then why to use stylesheets? Now you split `Grid/Button's` properties on a stylesheet and `myButton` definition, it is not a good coding practice.

At the end I only use stylesheets for cell/notebook related styles/actions and only in case where multiple notebooks. And it is a pity as it is only a consequence of minor issues not a fundamental limitation of them.

Comment: Thank you for the link! And thanks for the answer of course ;). That specifying `GridBoxItemSize` works this way is a bit surprising (I must have overlooked it when first looking at the `GridToBoxes` code...), but it seems to work without issues, even if the user specifies a custom `ItemSize`.