# How to draw a 3D polygon like this?

Tags: graphics3d, image3d

[image]

[image]

I tried to draw first picture with `Raster3D`, but the result is strange:

[image]

So, what is best function to call to draw 3d polygon like that?

Comment: Graphics3D[{Directive[Blue], Cuboid[]}] to start with

Comment: Related (if *quite* the superset of this question): [Mathematica Minecraft](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19669/131).

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of [Plotting Voxel in mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38925/plotting-voxel-in-mathematica).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is something to get you started,  look at [`Cuboid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cuboid.html)

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Directive[#1], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, #2]}] & @@@ {
   {Red, {1, 1, 1}},
   {Blue, {1, -1, 1}},
   {Green, {-1, -1, 1}},
   {Gray, {-1, 1, -1}},
   {Blue, {-1, 1, 1}}}
 , Boxed -> False]
```

[image]